# Returning an $http call followed by a .then does not seem to return correctly

Tags: angularjs

I have this code that calls a function and within that I return a function that calls $http.  When the code runs I cannot understand why I see

An alert saying "notok" followed by an alert saying "topicsRetrieve2 okay".

Should topicsRetrieve2 not be returning a failed promise if the $http fails?

```
topicsRetrieve = (): any => {
    this.topicsRetrieve2().then(() => {
        alert("topicsRetrieve2 okay");
    }, () => {
        alert("topicsRetrieve2 failed");
    })
}

topicsRetrieve2 = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    return this.$http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "badurlxxxxxxxx"
    })
        .then(() => {
            alert("ok");
        }, () => {
            alert("notok");
        })
```

AngularJS v1.4.1

Update: new potential solution:

```
topicsRetrieve2 = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var defer = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "badurlxxxxxxxx"
    })
        .then(() => {
            alert("ok");
            defer.resolve();
        }, () => {
            alert("notok");
            defer.reject()
        })
     return defer.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens in simple words.

1. Request fails with some error status.
2. You get into error callback getting `alert("notok")`.
3. Since you don't return new rejected promise from "notok"-callback or throw new error, it effectively means that you recovered from exceptional situation...
4. ... since you have recovered you get into success callback down the promise chain.

So if you provide an intermediate error callback ("notok" one) make sure to return new rejected promise for subsequent handlers in the chain:

```
topicsRetrieve2 = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    return this.$http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "badurlxxxxxxxx"
    })
    .then(() => {
        alert("ok");
    }, () => {
        alert("notok");
        throw new Error("notok");
    })
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me how I could return a new rejected promise or even better throw a new error?  If you could add a few lines to my code I would very much appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Thanks for adding.  Does the throw new Error have an option without a message and is that the same as if I didn't have the .then there?

Comment: I added an example. You either throw or `return Promise.reject("error")`;

Comment: I tried this but I get an error message saying "can't find Promise". I added a new solution to my question based on your comments. Do you think this is the way I should be doing it?  Note that I no longer have a return in front of this.$http.

Comment: Well you need to use your promise implementation. If you use Angular, then try `return $q.reject("error")`.

Comment: Regarding new potential solution, don't use it, it's called [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns), you don't need dummy deferred object, because you already have promise object to return.

Comment: Just saw your latest comment. I thought the only way was to create a defer object. I will try without.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit odd, what are you trying to do?

You are returning the result of the promise, not the promise itself. In topicsRetrieve2 all you want is

```
return this.$http.get('badurlxxxx');
```

without the .then inside of topicsRetrieve2. That way it'll return the promise and your .then inside of topicsRetrieve will execute on the success/failure

```
topicsRetrieve = (): any => {
    this.topicsRetrieve2().then(() => {
        alert("topicsRetrieve2 okay");
    }, () => {
        alert("topicsRetrieve2 failed");
    })
}

topicsRetrieve2 = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    return this.$http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "badurlxxxxxxxx"
    })
```

This will result in an alert with "topicsRetrieve2 failed", assuming badurlxxxxx does indeed return a non-400 :)